# Parent Theme not follow in the controller template prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Hi I have created a controller in which I am setting the template. It is a front controller. The problem I am getting is that the parent theme is not followed in the controller rather I just get another page uniquely all by itself and by the looks of it it is like that the template is not attached to the module. Currently the controller is just basic. I am beginner. I have attached the controller code. The code of my tpl file is also added. [I have attached an image to show the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBDDj.png)I haven't done any changes elsewhere just calling the controller from the module.php file by the link. Thank you in advance.

```
 //controller code

class ExperimentFirstPageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
public $ssl = true;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->bootstrap = true;
    parent::__construct();
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
}

public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array());
    $this->setTemplate('module:experiment/views/templates/front/list.tpl');
}

public function setMedia()
{
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->addjQuery();
}
}

//tpl file
<h>hello</h>
```

Comment: Have you tried `$this->setTemplate('list.tpl')`?

Comment: Yes I did and I got an error saying "No template found for list.tpl" [PrestaShopException]